# How to specify OpenMP execution policy in cuda thrust calls on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, thrust, visual-studio-2015

While porting a code from Linux to Windows, thanks to Visual Studio C++ 2015 Community, I encountered a compilation error that I cannot understand. 
Below is a sample program exhibiting this error, building a vector of doubles and then sorting it with cuda thrust, using OpenMP.

```
# include <thrust/sort.h>
# include <thrust/system/omp/execution_policy.h>
# include <chrono>
# include <random>
# include <vector>

double unit_random()
{
  static std::default_random_engine generator(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
  static std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(double(0), double(1));
  return distribution(generator);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  constexpr size_t input_size = 100000;
  std::vector< double > input(input_size, 0);
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < input_size; ++i)
    input[i] = unit_random() * 1000;

  thrust::sort(thrust::omp::par, input.begin(), input.end());
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the error seen in the Visual Studio console (file names are shortened):

```
thrust/system/omp/detail/sort.inl(136): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'nseg'
thrust/detail/sort.inl(83): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void thrust::system::omp::detail::stable_sort<thrust::system::omp::detail::par_t,RandomAccessIterator,StrictWeakOrdering>(thrust::system::omp::detail::execution_policy<thrust::system::omp::detail::par_t> &,RandomAccessIterator,RandomAccessIterator,StrictWeakOrdering)' being compiled
  with
  [
    RandomAccessIterator=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<double>>>,
    StrictWeakOrdering=thrust::less<value_type>
  ]
thrust/system/detail/generic/sort.inl(63): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void thrust::stable_sort<DerivedPolicy,RandomAccessIterator,StrictWeakOrdering>(const thrust::detail::execution_policy_base<DerivedPolicy> &,RandomAccessIterator,RandomAccessIterator,StrictWeakOrdering)' being compiled
  with
  [
      DerivedPolicy=thrust::system::omp::detail::par_t,
      RandomAccessIterator=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<double>>>,
      StrictWeakOrdering=thrust::less<value_type>
  ]
thrust/detail/sort.inl(56): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void thrust::system::detail::generic::sort<Derived,RandomAccessIterator,StrictWeakOrdering>(thrust::execution_policy<Derived> &,RandomAccessIterator,RandomAccessIterator,StrictWeakOrdering)' being compiled
  with
  [
      Derived=thrust::system::omp::detail::par_t,
      RandomAccessIterator=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<double>>>,
      StrictWeakOrdering=thrust::less<value_type>
  ]
thrust/system/detail/generic/sort.inl(49): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void thrust::sort<DerivedPolicy,RandomAccessIterator,thrust::less<value_type>>(const thrust::detail::execution_policy_base<DerivedPolicy> &,RandomAccessIterator,RandomAccessIterator,StrictWeakOrdering)' being compiled
  with
  [
      DerivedPolicy=thrust::system::omp::detail::par_t,
      RandomAccessIterator=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<double>>>,
      StrictWeakOrdering=thrust::less<value_type>
  ]
thrust/detail/sort.inl(41): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void thrust::system::detail::generic::sort<Derived,RandomAccessIterator>(thrust::execution_policy<Derived> &,RandomAccessIterator,RandomAccessIterator)' being compiled
  with
  [
      Derived=thrust::system::omp::detail::par_t,
      RandomAccessIterator=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<double>>>
  ]
windows_cuda_thrust_error.cc(24): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void thrust::sort<DerivedPolicy,std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<double>>>>(const thrust::detail::execution_policy_base<DerivedPolicy> &,RandomAccessIterator,RandomAccessIterator)' being compiled
  with
  [
      DerivedPolicy=thrust::system::omp::detail::par_t,
      RandomAccessIterator=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<double>>>
  ]
thrust/system/omp/detail/sort.inl(136): error C2275: 'IndexType': illegal use of this type as an expression
thrust/system/omp/detail/sort.inl(113): note: see declaration of 'IndexType'
thrust/system/omp/detail/sort.inl(136): error C2065: 'nseg': undeclared identifier
thrust/system/omp/detail/sort.inl(142): error C2065: 'nseg': undeclared identifier
thrust/system/omp/detail/sort.inl(159): error C2065: 'nseg': undeclared identifier
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The same code works fine on Linux.

**How are we supposed to specify an OpenMP execution policy in a cuda thrust call on Windows?** Alternatively, what I am doing wrong in this particular context?

The thrust version used is 1.8.1 and here is an excerpt of the thrust function, in file thrust/system/omp/detail/sort.inl, raising the compilation errors:

```
template<typename DerivedPolicy,
         typename RandomAccessIterator,
         typename StrictWeakOrdering>
void stable_sort(execution_policy<DerivedPolicy> &exec,
                 RandomAccessIterator first,
                 RandomAccessIterator last,
                 StrictWeakOrdering comp)
{
  // ...
  typedef typename thrust::iterator_difference<RandomAccessIterator>::type IndexType;

  if(first == last)
    return;

  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    thrust::system::detail::internal::uniform_decomposition<IndexType> decomp(last - first, 1, omp_get_num_threads());

    // process id
    IndexType p_i = omp_get_thread_num();

    // every thread sorts its own tile
    if(p_i < decomp.size())
    {
      thrust::stable_sort(thrust::seq,
                          first + decomp[p_i].begin(),
                          first + decomp[p_i].end(),
                          comp);
    }

    #pragma omp barrier

    IndexType nseg = decomp.size(); // line 136
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug of thrust. Hac3 you tried v1.8.3?

Comment: THRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM_OMP may not work as you expected as you are using host vectors.

Comment: @kangshiyin You are right, I mixed THRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM and THRUST_HOST_SYSTEM. Now I have the same errors for `thrust::sort(thrust::omp::par, input.begin(), input.end())` and `thrust::sort( input.begin(), input.end())`. I edited the question accordingly. I will try it on thrust version 1.8.3 later.

Comment: VS only have limited OpenMP support, up to version 2.0 -- maybe a problem

Comment: Same errors with thrust 1.8.3. Indeed, I believe this is more related to the OpenMP implementation (since `IndexType` is correctly recognized before line 136), but I cannot think this issue was not raised and fixed before (like a warning message when trying to use OpenMP host system to notify us that the CPP implementation will be used instead). Thus, I still believe I am doing something not correct with Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: You could file an issue on github and you will get quick reply. thrust is not well tested as you may expect. some very obvious bugs exist in 1.8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @kangshiyin, I filed an issue on github (see [issue #817](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/issues/817)) and thrust developers found a workaround. The problem came from the way MSVC currently deals with OpenMP code, so the code provided in the question was perfectly fine.

If a similar problem arise, try first to update to the latest version of thrust. You can also try to apply the same workaround: simply add a semi-colon before the line raising the error.